# What is the correct way to cater for loading another image when there is already an image loaded into the CImage object?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cimage

I thought I would try my code in debug mode:

```
void CSpecialEventVideoconferenceInfoDlg::OnEnChangeBrowseSpecialEventVideoconfPathImage()
{
    CString strImagePath;
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_BROWSE_SPECIAL_EVENT_VIDEOCONF_PATH_IMAGE, strImagePath);
    m_imgPreview.Load(strImagePath);
}
```

It is very simple and triggers `m_imgPreview` to load a new image. This variable is of type `CImage`. I notice in debug mode that when I select a **second** image that I get an exception raised:

```
inline void CImage::Attach(
    _In_ HBITMAP hBitmap,
    _In_ DIBOrientation eOrientation) throw()
{
    ATLASSUME( m_hBitmap == NULL );
    ATLASSERT( hBitmap != NULL );

    m_hBitmap = hBitmap;

    UpdateBitmapInfo(eOrientation);
}
```

It fails on this line:

```
ATLASSUME( m_hBitmap == NULL );
```

I have looked at the documentation for this ([`CImage::Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(ATLIMAGE%252FATL%253A%253ACImage%253A%253ALoad)%3Bk(ATL%253A%253ACImage%253A%253ALoad)%3Bk(Load)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170#load)) and it says nothing about this scenario. What is the correct way to cater for loading another image when there is already an image loaded into the `CImage` object?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have adjusted my code like this:

```
void CSpecialEventVideoconferenceInfoDlg::OnEnChangeBrowseSpecialEventVideoconfPathImage()
{
    CString strImagePath;
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_BROWSE_SPECIAL_EVENT_VIDEOCONF_PATH_IMAGE, strImagePath);

    if (!m_imgPreview.IsNull())
        m_imgPreview.Destroy();

    m_imgPreview.Load(strImagePath);
}
```

It appears to function still and I get no exceptions when selecting the next image. But if you think there is a better solution then please let me know.